# How can I check the value of record before updating?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I have this table:

```
// QandA
+----+-----------+-----------------+-------------+------+------+
| id |    post   | accepted-answer | question_id | let  | type |
+----+-----------+-----------------+-------------+------+------+
| 1  | question1 | null            | 1           | 200  | 0    |
| 2  | answer1   | null            | 1           | null | 1    |
| 3  | answer2   | 1               | 1           | null | 1    |
| 4  | answer3   | null            | 1           | null | 1    |
+----+-----------+-----------------+-------------+------+------+
//                                                        ^ 0 = question | 1 = answer
```

Also I have this query:

```
// this query changes accepted answer
UPDATE QandA
SET accepted_answer = IF(id <> :id, NULL, 1)
WHERE question_id = :question_id;
```

---

Now I'm trying to check `let` field before updating. Something like this:

```
if (`let` is null) then {update here}
else {don't update}
where `question_id` = :question_id and `type` = 0
```

How can I do that in MySQL?

Comment: Can you add ``and `let` is null`` to the where condition?

Comment: @Kateract emm, seems correct, I thought it is more harder .. Anyway thank you, I will try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the case statement , the below statement will update the QandA table .

It will set  accepted_answer to be 1 when let is null and the type is 0.

Give it a try , I know it works on ms sql , just cant access my sql box at the moment.

```
UPDATE QandA SET accepted_answer =  
CASE
  WHEN let = IS NULL THEN 1
END
WHERE type= 0;
```

Comment: Thank you .. up vote. Just in reality, there isn't just one row `type = 0`. So I think you have to improve the `where` clause in your query.

Comment: I am sure you can just add the addition check do you want `question_id` = :question_id to be in the where , if so just check.